# New object in Java is sending a compilation error

Tags: java

The code I'm trying to compile is:

```
    class Drumkit {
    boolean topHat = true;
    boolean snare = true;

    void playSnare() {
        System.out.println("bang bang ba-bang");
    }

    void playTopHat() {
        System.out.println("ding ding da-ding");
    }
}

class DrumKitTestDrive {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Drumkit d = new DrumKit();
        d.playSnare();
        d.playTopHat();
        d.snare = false;
        if (d.snare == true) {
            d.playSnare();
        }
    }
}
```

But the output is:

```
C:\JavaTests>javac DrumKitTestDrive.java
DrumKitTestDrive.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
                Drumkit d = new DrumKit();
                                ^
  symbol:   class DrumKit
  location: class DrumKitTestDrive
1 error
```

I don't understand why is it wrong?
Excuse me if it is a dumb question, but I'm learning and I think the code is alright.
Thank you.

Comment: typo: `Drumkit d = new Drumkit();`

Comment: It should be `new Drumkit();` and not `new DrumKit();` with a lower case `k`.

Comment: Java is case-sensitive. `Drumkit` != `DrumKit`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just missed to capitalize the `k` in `Drumkit`.

Here: `Drumkit d = new DrumKit();`. Change to this:

```
Drumkit d = new Drumkit();
```

Remember that Java is case-sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that DrumKit is imported (if it is not in the same file as the tester) and you change: Drumkit d = new DrumKit(); to Drumkit d = new Drumkit(); because Java is case-sensitive and Drumkit is the name of your class.

Comment: This is wrong on 2 different levels.

Comment: for good measure i'll explain: 1. He didn't need to import anything as you can see they are on the same file even... 2. You *always* have a default constructor in java, even if you didn't declare one yourself.

Comment: My bad on the default constructor but we don't know if he just pasted the code from two different files or if it is like that in actuality. I find it to be better safe than sorry. Also, in his code his Class is called Drumkit; he should do the opposite of the solution you posted correct?